# Strange/incorrect output from php date (formatting) function

Tags: php, datetime

I'm having an issue trying to convert a Unix time (taken from an XML file generated by an  SVN Info command) into to a formatted date/time.

The `$svnInfoTime` is correct, and the generated `$unixTime` reflects this, though the `$formattedDate` seems to be slightly out.

I've seen this occur in a number of (but not all) cases.  An example:

```
<?php 
    $svnInfoTime = "2013-03-06T15:42:00.894378Z";
    $unixTime = strtotime($svnInfoTime);
    $formattedDate = date('d F, Y, h:i A', $unixTime);

    echo "SVN info time : " . $svnInfoTime . "<br>";
    echo "unix time     : " . $unixTime . "<br>";
    echo "formatted date: " . $formattedDate . "<br>";
>
```

outputs:

```
SVN info time : 2013-03-06T15:42:00.894378Z
unix time : 1362584520
formatted date: 06 March, 2013, 04:42 PM
```

Why is the formatted date displaying 4:42 pm, when the Unix time is 3:42 pm??

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Learn to use DateTime objects that are timezone aware

Comment: Another workaround is to set default time zone: `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`.

Comment: You forgot to define "time" adequately precisely, is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP's [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function takes your timezone settings into account when outputting/formatting dates.

Check which timezone you are located in, or pass your custom timezone settings to the `date` function to get output as *3:42 PM*.

P.S. It works fine on [codepad.viper-7.com](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RuYojs)

---

### EDIT

On passing a different [timezone(`Asia/Kolkata`)](http://codepad.viper-7.com/d4XO9a) before the `date()` call, results in the output **9:12 PM**.

```
$svnInfoTime = "2013-03-06T15:42:00.894378Z";
$unixTime = strtotime($svnInfoTime);
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$formattedDate = date('d F, Y, h:i A', $unixTime);
echo "SVN info time : " . $svnInfoTime . "<br>";
echo "unix time     : " . $unixTime . "<br>";
echo "formatted date: " . $formattedDate . "<br>";
```

gives:

> SVN info time : 2013-03-06T15:42:00.894378Z 
>   unix time : 1362584520 
>   formatted date: 06 March, 2013, 09:12 PM

Comment: Thanks, fixed issue by using `date_default_timezone_set('GMT');` before calling the `date` function.